# What Is The Status Of Khalid Bin Yazeed Ansari As A Hadith Narrator?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

I am trying to verify the authenticity of a hadith that has been transmitted through the following chain of narrators:-

***Khalid bin Yazeed Ansari <= Ibn Abi Zi’b <= Nafee <= Ibn Omar <= Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alaihiwassalam)***

What is the status of Khalid bin Yazid Ansari in this chain and is this chain acceptable?

Comment: Is ot really Yazeed not Zayd or Ziyaad? I guess it would be best to have the hadith at hands. Because ibn abi Dhi'b hadca lot of students most biographers only list the most famous ones.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - I am talking about this Hadith: "There will come a time upon the people when nothing will remain of Islam except its name and nothing will remain of the Quran except its words. Their mosques will be splendidly furnished but destitute of guidance". I am talking about the isnad of this narration which can be found in Daylami's Musnad. The isnad of this hadith mentioned in my question is found in Daylami's Musnad.

Comment: Either this person is Khalid ibn Yazeed al-Umari (al-'Amri) or he is unknown. In both cases this is hardly a support for the authenticity of the hadith all other versions already are considered as as very weak or fabricated.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - So, you mean Khalid ibn Yazid Al-Amri is a weak narrator of Hadith? I will really appreciate if you can provide some references that state that he is weak. I know that all other versions are weak but what about this specific version? Thanks.